# Android Custom Spinner elements with sub child

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am looking for custom `Spinner` with expandable child elements. Like I want to click on the spinner view , it shows the ExpandablelistView main categories inside it, then by clicking any of the main category, the sub categories will be shown. Like reference image.[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: try this ref: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/10/android-expandablelistview-example.html. hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks @DaminiMehra but it's not going to work.

Comment: I think I can do this with the help of PopupMenu http://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example

Answer (score 0):

Spinner and ExpandableListview are two independent views so you can not embedded one into the other. But I have some solution for you here:
1.)Add a spinner to main layout
2.)Add a ExpandableListView to main layout
3.)Then On Click/Touch event of spinner you have to show the listview on spinner's bottom.
Note: Data which you want to show in spinner then you have to show it in listview
It is just for your suggestion..